# How to index file contents

Tags: windows, batch-file, search, indexing, server

I have a server at [batalabs.tk](https://www.batalabs.tk) where I use batch files as most of my CGI scripts, I am currently trying to make an Indexing service for a search script...

Example files:

## Directory to search:

```
<DIR HTDOCS>
    index.html
    otherpage1.html
    otherpage2.html
</DIR>
```

## index.html:

```
<HTML>
    <HEAD>
        <TITLE>MyWebsite - Buy Products</TITLE>
        <META NAME="Description" Content="Buy Software and products from MyWebsite">
    </HEAD>
    <BODY>
        <DIV ALIGN="CENTER">
            <H2>Software</H2>
            <h4>Find the latest and greatest in software right here at the Shop Page!</h4>
            <hr>
            <A Href="/buy/lorum">Lorum - Free Cloud Storage</a>
            <hr>
            <A Href="/buy/ipsum">Ipsum - Free Networking Software</a>
            <hr>
        </div>
        Copyright MyWebsite.com, 2016
    </body>
</html>
```

## Otherpage1.html

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Page One - Hello World!</title>
        <META Name="Description" Content="Hello World Page For Testing.">
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>
            Hello, World!
        </h1>
        <div>
            <pre>
                this is an example page for use with testing.
                Any of these words can be searched and should (optimally) show this page in the results.
            </pre>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

## otherpage2.html:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Page Two - The Revenge Of The Coder</title>
        <meta Name="Tags" content="dummy; coder; file; otherpage2;;">
    </head>
    <body>
        <pre>
            Hello, This file doesn't matter. At all. It is a dummy.
        </pre>
    </body>
</html>
```

These are just example files, But i want my batch file to pick up on the
 `<META>` tag with `Description` and `Tags`, as well as the file's name, every word in the body,
and the title... I've tried some stuff to no avail, any help?

---

---

So maybe a user could type "`dummy`" as their keyword, and Otherpage2.html would pop up like so:

```
Page Two - The Revenge Of The Coder

HTTPS://www.batalabs.tk/otherpage2.html
Hello, this file doesn't matter. At all. It is a dummy.
```

Comment: I am running this on Windows 10 using Apache.

Comment: You have not provided any code for us to help you with.

Comment: @Squashman I guess the gist of my question is "How do I make a searchable index of a directory using batch?"

Comment: Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: @cascading-style Are you executing the batch script as a CGI script to serve content to a web browser?  Or are you intending to use the batch script from the console, and have the `node.innerText` dumped to the console?  Your best bet will probably be to use a different language -- JScript or PowerShell.  If you must have .bat files, you can make a polyglot / hybrid script.  [Batch + JScript example](https://gist.github.com/davidruhmann/5199433) | [Batch + PowerShell example](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?p=45095#p45095).  Then just use DOM methods to parse your HTML.

Comment: @cascading-style There are advantages to both.  If you plan to parse all web pages with each run, then JScript will probably be faster.  On the other hand, if you have thousands of pages, if you plan to index all files periodically and make a hash table of tag = [page,page,page] to store in a database of some sort, then using PowerShell and .NET StreamReader methods can be faster than parsing the entirety of thousands of pages.

Comment: @rojo I am trying to have the batch file crawl my website, and return google-like results when the client enters a query into the search cgi script. so there are two scripts, one to index the files periodically, and one as a cgi to search the index for the query. Essentially i am making a search engine. I have tried a couple of VBscript solutions i have found, but none of those work. And I feel like there should be a rather simple pure batch solution.

Comment: The `findstr` command does exactly what you are asking for. I recommend reading [the list of batch commands](http://ss64.com/nt/) before asking further questions here.

Comment: @SomethingDark `findstr` does not answer my question at all.

Comment: `findstr "dummy" *.html` will absolutely return all HTML files that contains the string "dummy"

Comment: @SomethingDark I would ideally like to create a database, and reference that instead of the filesystem every time a user searches for something. And `findstr` produces strange output that would have to be parsed in excess.

Comment: @cascading-style What type of database? SQLite? Access? MySQL? A flat ini file? Have you given any planning at all to the mechanics of your project, or did you just intend to post a 50 point bounty and have someone write it for you from start to finish? To do it right will require more time and effort than I daresay anyone would be willing to donate for 50 points. If you had a specific issue, such as "How do I add a row to a SQLite database using PowerShell", that might get you better results. You need to do more planning and show us some code.

Comment: @rojo most likely a flat INI file or a text file. Possibly an XML file. Those are the only files I know how to  parse using batch.

Comment: I've decided that this is impossible, and have given up on it.